# Undefined method build, build has_many association in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, has-many

I have the following problem:
I have to create a new associated row in my database.
I have:

```
companies table

references table
```

Companies `has_many` References.

References `belongs_to` Company.

In my Company table i have the following attribute:

```
id | city | email | ...|
```

In my Reference table i have the following attribute:

```
id | name | surname | company_id | ...|
```

Company.rb model:

```
belongs_to :references
```

Reference.rb model:

```
has_many :companies
```

In Company controller:

```
  def create

    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    @company.references.build(params[:company][:email_r])   
        respond_to do |format|  
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to companies_index_path, :notice => 'created'}
        format.json { render :json => companies_index_path, :status => :created, :location => @company }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @company.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My error is:

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your table schema, associations should be like - `company has many references` and `reference belong to a company`. In `Company.rb` it should be like below -

```
class Company
  has_many :references
end
```

And in `Reference.rb` it should be like

```
class Reference 
   belongs_to :company
end
```

Comment: yes , i inverted the things.. i'm really sorry. Now it works. There is another error in my code. This    @company.references.build(params[:company][:email_r])  should be: @company.references.create(:email_r => params[:company][:email_r]). Thank you